# Boost.Log ignores overloaded stream insertion operator

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, boost-log, widestring

I have a class that I want to appear in log in a certain way, so I've overloaded its `<<` operator:

```
class CWindowClassId
{
public:
    // ...
    friend std::wostream& operator<< (std::wostream& os, CWindowClassId const& classId);
}
```

Inserting the class above in log stream:

```
// ...
CWindowClassId classId(hWindow);
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "Window created, class = " << classId;
```

causes compilation error:

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Sandbox::CWindowClassId' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    C:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\log\utility\formatting_ostream.hpp  710
```

I know the error lies in the fact, that I've overloaded `<<` for wide strings. All is fine when I use `ostream` instead of `wostream`, but I really want to use wide string version.

I've tried to set locale for a sink:

```
shared_ptr<log::sinks::synchronous_sink<log::sinks::text_file_backend> > sink = log::add_file_log("log.txt");
sink->imbue(boost::locale::generator()("en_US.UTF-8"));
```

And have `BOOST_LOG_USE_WCHAR_T` defined before any log-related includes.

Is there anything I can do to make logging work with wide string `<<` operator?

I'm using Boost 1.55.0.

Comment: Lacking a more complete view of what you do in your code, I suggest you read up on argument dependent lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL`. The trivial logger uses a underlying `boost::sources::logger` instead of `boost::sources::wlogger`, you can see that from trivial.hpp and trivial.cpp in the boost source file, and I can't see how we can change it unless we modify the source code. If you use a `wlogger`, it would work. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>

namespace src = boost::log::sources;

class CWindowClassId
{
public:
    // ...
    friend std::wostream& operator<< (std::wostream& os, CWindowClassId const& classId)
    {
        os << classId.ws;
        return os;
    }
public:
    std::wstring ws;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    src::wlogger lg;
    CWindowClassId id;
    id.ws = L"wide char";
    BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello, World! This is a wide character message."<<id;
    return 0;
}
```